# Minimal binding TextBlock to property

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp

It's been sometime since I coded something in XAML, and, trying to update an old app, I stopped at an issue with binding. I stripped everything to come up to a minimal example.

Here is my XAML body:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PageTitle, ElementName=page, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

My code behind has this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property PageTitle As String
    Get
        Return "My page"
    End Get
End Property
```

I believe this is the minimal code (ok, exluding the `Mode=OneWay part`, since we are talking about a TextBlock) required to bind this TextBlock content to a property on its underlying page, yet it doesn't work and I come up with an empty TextBlock. The `Get` code of my PageTitle property is never called.

I even went as far as implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` by declaring:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements  INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

and then raising `RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("PageTitle"))` in my `OnNavigatedTo` code, but to no avail.

So, what's the simple thing I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the `Name` of the `Page`?

However, if the property is defined in the code-behind of the view, you could use [x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) without setting the `DataContext`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PageTitle, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out setting the name of the page. I had it defined as `x:Name="Page", but I was referring to `ElementName=page` and XAML is page-sensitive. Of course `x:Bind` works as well and is the better solution in this example.